# Rewrite rule for custom permalink structure

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a Custom permalink Structure setup Settings > Permalinks as:

/%category%/%postname%.html

But I want  my url structure to replace /%category%/ by /%articles%/, so it looks like- mydomain.com/%articles%/%postname%-%post_ID.html
Will anybody help me?

Comment: Is there an example you can provide? What are articles vs categories? Are you looking for something like example.com/articles/blog-title-5.html (where blog title represents the "postname" and 5 is the post_ID)?

Comment: Yes.. I mean there should be a word "articles" before post name....like the sites Wall Street Journal (wsj.com) and Reuter.com have. The post_ID should be unique for each and every post and it should consist 7 to 9 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments in the question, I believe I have an answer.

Visit your WP Admin Dashboard (example.com/wp-admin/) and click on Settings, then Permalinks.

Here you will want to choose "Custom Structure" and use the following structure (copy/paste):

`/articles/%postname%-%post_id%.html`

This will enable the slug "articles" and the structure you are looking for, which is post name and ID.

The only catch here is the WordPress ID's are not as long as you are looking for. These IDs in the database start from 1 and increment with each post.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If i did it this way then if i clixk on pagess like contact us then it "articles" shows up in the url box despite that i want it to be shown for posts only, basicallg it can be done by rewrite rule but the problem is i don't know it.